# How can I get the monitor resolution using the command line?

Tags: command-line, resolution, xfce, desktop-background

I would like to find a wallpaper that best suits my resolution. How can I get the resolution just by writing commands in the command line?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/196545/416849):

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
```

Or to get just the resolution:

```
xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/{print $2}'
```

OR

```
xdpyinfo  | grep -oP 'dimensions:\s+\K\S+'
```

Comment: It works for a single monitor setup but with two monitors it sums both dimensions, for me my two screens return: `3520x1200 pixels`

Comment: Good point. On the other hand, this is still useful if he's searching for a single wallpaper to be spanned over all monitors.

Comment: Indeed you're right, +1 ;)

Comment: @aguslr What would be the point of that? Having two 2000x1000 monitors, what use would be a 4000x2000 wallpaper image?

Comment: @Jos, I get it this command would return 4000x1000, that is, it puts both monitors next to each other. For example, Sylvain has two monitors (1600x900 and 1920x1200) and he gets 3520x1200.

Comment: @aguslr Ah yes, you are probably right. I took his "it sums both dimensions" too literally.

Comment: @Jos Sorry for the confusion, I can remove my first comment if needed

Comment: Does it show monitor or GPU resolution?

Answer (score 43):

I would just use `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here I have two screens, the resolution are:

- 1600x900 (laptop)
- 1920x1200 (monitor)

To get only the resolution of your primary monitor, you can also use this python oneliner:

```
$ python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Gdk; screen=Gdk.Screen.get_default(); \
geo = screen.get_monitor_geometry(screen.get_primary_monitor()); \
print(geo.width, "x", geo.height)'
1920 x 1200
```

To get the resolution of your extanded desktop (for a multi monitor setup):

```
$ python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Gdk; screen=Gdk.Screen.get_default(); \
print(screen.get_width(), "x", screen.get_height())'
3520 x 1200
```

Comment: xrandr + vesa = no workee.

Comment: Just the resolution of in-use displays: `xrandr | grep  " connected\|\*"`

Answer (score 10):

The request was for the *resolution*.  That is given by

```
xdpyinfo | grep resolution
```

Comment: Typically, people use resolution to mean the dimensions. The DPI is not of as much concern as the dimensions are.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
 xrandr | grep ' connected'
```

Example of output on one of my machines:

```
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
```

Answer (score 5):

On a raspberry pi without X, I was able to get the screen resolution by running:

```
fbset -s
```

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get your current screen's resolution as follows:

1. Get the X resolution by running:

   ```bsh
   X=$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1)
   ```
2. Get the Y resolution by running:

   ```bsh
   Y=$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f2)
   ```
3. Output the X and Y resolution by running:

   ```bsh
   echo "$X"x"$Y"
   ```

That should be possible to do like this without using `awk` too.

One alternate way is:

You can start by terminal your preferred website which show you your screen resolution.

```
firefox https://de.piliapp.com/what-is-my/screen-resolution/
```

You can show the webpage on your terminal too by useing https://www.brow.sh/

If you like, you can skrapping this page by terminal by include appropriate python website skrapping tools and export the output to a terminal var.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use xprop:

```
$ xprop -notype -len 16 -root _NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY | cut -c 25-
11520, 1080
```

If anyone cares, it was slightly faster on my machine than grepping xdpyinfo

Or, if you only care about width:

```
$ xprop -notype -len 8 -root _NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY | cut -c 25-
11520
```

Tested only on multiple displays organized via Xinerama.

Comment: If one has two connected monitors, this seems to give their sum of dimensions.

Comment: xprop gives me incorrect dimensions when the monitor is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, when using multiple connected displays and/or offsets with TwinView then xdpyinfo will give you the resolution of the entire set of displays the way they are configured. If you require the resolution of a single monitor or a monitor connected to one of the display ports you need to use xrandr. However, even in that configuration xrandr can be unreliable and not show the resolution. See this example entry from my X windows config file:

```
Option "MetaModes" "DP-1: 1440x900 +0+0, DP-3: 1440x900 +1568+0, DP-5: 1440x900 +3136+0"
```

The xrandr output looks like this:

```
DVI-D-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1440x900      59.89 +  74.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected 1440x900+1568+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

You can see that DP-3 isn't showing a resolution on the line that a grep for "connected" would show. So the best, most consistent, and reliable command I've found for identifying the resolution of any individual connected display is:

```
/usr/bin/xrandr --query|/usr/bin/grep -A 1 connected|grep -v connected
```

which produces this:

```
   1440x900      59.89*+
--
   1440x900      59.89*+  74.98
--
   1440x900      59.89*+
```

At that point, it's pretty trivial to pick out the different resolutions or grep for only one port.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `xrandr | grep '\bconnected\b'`.

Cheers!

Comment: Thats output a lot of thinks, including the monitor resolution...

Answer (score -1):

You can get the monitor resulution on follow way by bash:

```
read x y < <(xrandr --current | grep -oP '\d+x\d+' | tr x ' ')
echo $x
echo $y
```

Comment: @Downvoter, thats works fine on my system.